# JavaFX snapshot all content tree/table view

Tags: javafx, snapshot, treetableview

I want to export my tree table view content to .png file. But when I use snapshot but the snapshot is only grabbing the tableview that is visible on the screen. I search all form about this problem but does not find any solution. Can any suggestion. how can export all content of table to png(also pdf or xls file)

[Snapshot entire TableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27595096/snapshot-entire-tableview)
does not help me

Comment: The [solution you linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27595096/snapshot-entire-tableview) looks like a reasonable workaround. Why does that not work for you?

Comment: Because i use tree table i have 5 children under root and each of them have own children can be more than 10. Also my table has nested column. Snapsbot takes only visible part.

Comment: So it's more complicated, but I think the basic idea in that example (represent the same data in a different layout, and snapshot it) is the right way to go.

Comment: I think the problem is snapshot takes only visible part. If we have large entire it is not possible all entire in a page. The simple way i thought scroll down table view programmatically  and take snapshot each time

Comment: But if you construct a new layout, which doesn't include automatic scrolling, the "visible part" contains everything. It's not the snapshot that's truncating it, it's the `TableView`.

Comment: Ok think that you have more than 100 data so which layout shows all data without scrolling

Comment: No layouts have automatics scrolling. Only certain controls (`ListView`, `TableView`, `TreeView`, etc, and `TextArea`) do.